# Using AngularJS how to check a PDF file exist in a folder or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I have a list of students.
For some students I have to show a link, and on clicking this link their progress card should load (it is a .pdf file). For others, the link should not be shown.

I have done this by giving the same student id to their progress card and if it is this particular student then show the link; otherwise, don't show the link. I can do it this way for only 5 or 6 students. I cant do this for 1000 students.

The following is my AngularJS code:

```js
if (response.student_id == 'SD0001' || response.student_id == 'SD0002' || response.student_id == 'SD0004') {  
    $scope.pdfData = true;
    $scope.StudentPDFFile =  response.student_id+'.pdf';
} else {
    $scope.pdfData = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<body id="ng-app" ng-app>
    <div ng-switch on="pdfData">
        <div ng-switch-when="false"></div>
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
            <span class="font-10">Download Performance Report</span>
            <a href="http://www.example.com/s-pdf/{{StudentPDFFile}}" target="_blank">­ click here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here I haven't specified the controller, this is skeleton functionality is working for me.

For 1000 records how I can do this?

Comment: tell me the reson for redusing my points

Comment: If you start a bounty the amount is reduced from your points regardless wheter you get an answer or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a http request to determine if the file exists *as long as you are on the same domain as the pdf file*.

For a given student ID (which in your code appears to be `response.student_id`) it looks like this:

```
if(response.student_id) {  
    var url = 'http://www.example.com/s-pdf/' + response.student_id + '.pdf';
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('HEAD', url, false);
    request.send();
    if(request.status == 200) {
        $scope.pdfData = true;
        $scope.StudentPDFFile =  response.student_id+'.pdf';
    } else {
        $scope.pdfData = false;
    }
} else {
    $scope.pdfData = false;
}
```

The `'HEAD'` is all that is necessary to ensure that the file exists; you could also use `'GET'` but it doesn't seem like you need the whole file in this situation.

Comment: request.send is not working i given next to request.send();alert("hi"); its not alert anything.So I thing request.send has the problem. Please help me

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at the link. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: As luigi says, you have to be on the same domain as the file you're trying to fetch is

Comment: "Same domain" means that if your .pdf file is located in folder `http://www.example.com/s-pdf/`, the code needs to be executed from a page on that domain, like `www.example.com/index.html`

Comment: For debugging on the same domain, a super simple way is to use your browser's dev tools (usually CTRL+SHIFT+I) on the page you want to test, and then you can just copy/paste the commands into the console. That way you can mess around and be sure you're on the correct domain.

Comment: Or anotherway if you have control on domain from where you request information you can Add CORS headers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 2):

This is another way. 
You can make a directive and verify an attrib with this directive and set anything you want in the element.

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('imgCheck', ['$http', function($http){
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                $http.get('/img/'+attrs.imgCheck)
                     .success(function(data, status){
                        if(status==200){
                            attrs.$set('src','/img/'+attrs.imgCheck)
                        }else{
                            attrs.$set('src','/img/not-found.png')
                        }
                     })
                     .error(function(data,status){
                        if(status==200){
                            attrs.$set('src','/img/'+attrs.imgCheck)
                        }else{
                            attrs.$set('src','/img/not-found.png')
                        }
                     });
            }
        };
```

}]);

**HTML**

```
<figure class="podcast-item col-md-2" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" img-check="{{image.url}}" />
    </a>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ng-show` seems more appropriate:

```
<div ng-show="pdfData">
     <span class="font-10">Download Performance Report</span>
     <a href="http://www.example.com/s-pdf/{{StudentPDFFile}}" target="_blank">­ click here</a> 
</div>
```

For 1000, put it in a `ng-repeat` then you should better, test all the PDFs in one request and keep it in a cached list.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple bro, you just have to use ng-reapeat and ng-show. Below is my code with fiddle example, I hope it works for you.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="studentApp">
  <h2>List of Students</h2>
  <div ng-controller="studentController">

      <div ng-repeat="student in students">
          Student Name :  <strong>{{student.name}}</strong><br>
          <div ng-show="{{student.url}}"><a href="{{student.url}}" title="" >Download PDF</a><br></div>
          <hr>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('studentApp', [])
  .controller('studentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.students = [
        {name: 'John', url:'abc.com/files/1.pdf'},
        {name: 'Peter', url:''},
        {name: 'Kerry', url:'abc.com/files/1.pdf'},
        {name: 'Silly', url:'f'},
        ]




  }]);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/asadalikanwal/3a2zvrht/3/
Just change the PDF path with you once. If you have any question shoot