# angular-resource: Judgment method when a file does not exist

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I get Json file, use $resource.

```
var resource = $resource('example.json')
// Some kind of processing using the resource
var response = resource.query();
```

The contents of the file are as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": "12345"
  }
]
```

but, When a file does not exist, it becomes the error.

How should I confirm that a json file does not exist before execute query method, use resource object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using AngularJS how to check a PDF file exist in a folder or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270862/using-angularjs-how-to-check-a-pdf-file-exist-in-a-folder-or-not)

Comment: thx Vineet. but i want to know the method using the resource object.

Comment: `var request = new XMLHttpRequest();request.open('HEAD', 'exampl.json', false);request.send();console.log(request.status);` status is '200', when 'example.json' dose not exsit. Why??